# when i run a url i got 0/1 in browser how can i retrive it to android app

Tags: android, json

this is my browser image.I need to retrieve it to my android app.No way i can change the value or add parenthesis before or after the given value.as json need some parenthesis will it work here.The value is in the top left corner of the image ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzM6M.png)

ex
when i run www.example.com as post in browser i got value 0 it top left corner of browser how can i retrive it in android app

Comment: Most of your question seems to be missing.

Comment: i need to retrieve a value to android app.using post function. The value is generated by an api. when i run the url it in browser  i got value 1 in top left corner

Comment: when i run www.example.com as post in browser i got value 0 it top left corner of browser how can i retrive it in android app